# How to pass Page Number from component.html Angular 13 to web api?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, angular13

I work on a web application with ASP.NET Core 6 and Angular 13.

This application displays a list of items successfully without any issue.

**My issue How to Pass Page Number from to Web Api using Angular 13?**

What I tried is:

(1) Create Web API action to display all items

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber)
{
    var allitems = _iitem.GetAllItems();

    var result = _pageHelper.GetPage(allitems.AsQueryable(), pageNumber);

    var itemsdata = new ItemsPageViewModel
            {
                items = result.Items,
                Pager = result.Pager
            };

    return Ok(itemsdata);
}
```

When I call this action method, it returns json data as shown here:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "itemNameEN": "pen"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "itemNameEN": "pencil"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "itemNameEN": "pen2"
        }
    ],
    "pager": {
        "numberOfPages": 1,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalRecords": 3
    }
}

(2) I created a component items logic in component.ts:

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveAllItems();
  }
 
 retrieveAllItems(): void {
  this.erpservice.getAll()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
   
        this.items = data.items;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

(3) I created a component view component.html:

```
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>ItemNameEN</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.itemNameEN}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to pass Page Number from Angular 13 to  web api ?

I install `ngxPagination module`

and add below lines

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <pagination-controls
      previousLabel="Prev"
      nextLabel="Next"
      [responsive]="true"
    ></pagination-controls>
  </div>
```

**my issue how to pass page number from component.html to web api ?**

**updated post**
page number not display as
1 2
only display previous and next
so How to display it

**last updated post**

i get error when apply pagination on html

```
optional (property) ItemsComponent.items?: ItemsData[] | undefined
```

error display on items collection

items.html as below

```
<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>ItemNameAR</th>
    <th>ItemNameEN</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr
    *ngFor="
      let item of items
        | paginate
          : {
              itemsPerPage: pager?.numberOfPages,
              currentPage: pager?.currentPage,
              totalItems: pager?.totalRecords
            }
    "
  >
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
  <td>{{item.itemNameAR}}</td>
  <td>{{item.itemNameEN}}</td>
  <td>{{item.description}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<pagination-controls
  previousLabel="Prev"
  nextLabel="Next"
  [responsive]="true"
  (pageChange)="onPageChanged($event)" 
></pagination-controls>
```

items.ts

```
items?:ItemsData[];
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.retrieveAllItems();
  }
  onPageChanged(pageNumber: number) {
    this.retrieveAllItems(pageNumber);
  }



retrieveAllItems(pageNumber: number = 0): void {
    this.erpservice.getAll(pageNumber)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
        this.items=data.items;
        this.pager=data.pager;

       
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }

export interface ItemsData {
    id:number;
    itemNameER:string;
    itemNameAR:string;
    itemNameEN:string;
    description:string;
}

getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<DataWrapper> {
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (pageNumber)
      params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    let httpOptions = {
        params: params
    };
    return this.http.get<DataWrapper>(baseUrl,httpOptions);
  }

export interface DataWrapper {
    items: ItemsData[];
    pager:Pager;
}

export interface Pager {
    numberOfPages:number;
    currentPage:number;
    totalRecords:number;
}
```

[image: issue error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PaginationControlsComponent documentation](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination/blob/master/README.md#paginationcontrolscomponent)

> pageChange [event handler] The expression specified will be invoked whenever the page changes via a click on one of the pagination controls. The $event argument will be the number of the new page. This should be used to update the value of the currentPage variable which was passed to the PaginatePipe.

1. Add the `pageChange` event to `<<pagination-controls>` that trigger the `onPageChanged` method and pass the current page value when the page is changed.

```
<pagination-controls
  previousLabel="Prev"
  nextLabel="Next"
  [responsive]="true"
  (pageChange)="onPageChanged($event)" 
></pagination-controls>
```

2. Implement the `onPageChanged` method.

```
onPageChanged(pageNumber: number) {
  this.retrieveAllItems(pageNumber);
}
```

3. Possible that you need to modify the `retrieveAllItems` method signature to support the `pageNumber` parameter as optional.

```
retrieveAllItems(pageNumber: number = 1): void {
  this.erpservice.getAll(pageNumber)
    .subscribe(...);
}
```

4. The `getAll` method in the `ErpService` service is also required to support the page number. Unsure what is your API URL with page number, I assume your API URL is something like:

> https://<your-domain-URL>/api/<action>/{pageNumber}

```
export class ErpService {
  ...

  baseUrl = '<your-domain-URL>';
   
  getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<ItemsPageViewModel> {
    // Pass the pageNumber to url. Example:
    let apiUrl = this.baseUrl + '/<action>'; // Replace <action> based on your API url

    if (pageNumber)
      apiUrl += `/${pageNumber}`;

    return this.http.get<ItemsPageViewModel>(apiUrl);
  }
}
```

---

**For passing `pageNumber` to API as query params**

If you implement the `GetAll` API to retrieve `pageNumber` from query params

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromQuery]int pageNumber)
{
    ...
}
```

On the Angular side, you should pass the `pageNumber` with `HttpParams`.

```
export class ErpService {
  ...

  baseUrl = '<your-domain-URL>';
   
  getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<ItemsPageViewModel> {
    let apiUrl = this.baseUrl + '/<action>'; // Replace <action> based on your API url

    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (pageNumber)
      params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

    let httpOptions = {
        params: params
    };

    return this.http.get<ItemsPageViewModel>(apiUrl, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

---

**Issue: Page Number is not showing**

You need to apply `PaginatePipe` as shown in this [Server Paging Example | ngx-pagination](http://michaelbromley.github.io/ngx-pagination/#/server-paging).

1. Apply `PaginatePipe` on `items` by providing info such as `itemsPerPage`, `currentPage` and `totalItems`.

```
<tr
  *ngFor="
    let item of items
      | paginate
        : {
            itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
            currentPage: pager?.currentPage,
            totalItems: pager?.totalRecords
          }
  "
>
  ...
</tr>
```

2. Retrieve the `pager` info from the API response.

```
export class AppComponent {
  pager: Pager;
  itemsPerPage: number = 3;

  ...

  retrieveAllItems(pageNumber: number = 1): void {
    this.erpservice.getAll(pageNumber).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.items = data.items;
        this.pager = data.pager;

        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6pjbzo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thank you for support and help i face some issues as how to send url api after add from query to api my main url as https://localhost:7235/api/items so after add pageNumber what url will be

Comment: If you implement the `FromQuery` attribute in your API, by right you should follow my Angular side for the *For passing pageNumber to API as query params* section. In the end, it should be something like: `return this.http.get<ItemsPageViewModel>('localhost:7235/api/items', httpOptions);`

Comment: sorry for late i will reply quickly i test your answer but i face issue how to display pages 1,2,3, etc it not display

Comment: Hi @ahmedbarbary, done update my answer. You have to apply the `PaginatePipe` for the page number.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but did you check and try the answer I posted? And what issue did you face? Spamming sentences like *so how to do it please* and *can you help me please* are not useful. At least you should try to provide more info as what I had mentioned above.

Comment: i updated original post with issue

Comment: The `items` is possibly undefined. You can use ngIf directive to show the table/row when `items` has value. `<tr *ngIf="items" *ngFor="let item of items | paginate: {...}">`

Comment: it give me error when apply ngif with ng for

Comment: i updated original post with full ts and html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250987/discussion-between-yong-shun-and-ahmed-barbary).