# Angular 13 - How to get pager details from the JSON response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular13

I work on Angular 13 and I face an issue in that I can't retrieve pager data from the JSON.

The `items` array returned success but I can't return pager details.

So how to do it?

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "itemNameER": "قلم",
            "itemNameEN": "pen",
            "description": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "itemNameER": "قلم",
            "itemNameEN": "pencil",
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "itemNameER": "قلم",
            "itemNameEN": "pen2",
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "itemNameER": "car",
            "itemNameEN": "car",
            "description": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "itemNameER": "mobile",
            "itemNameEN": "mobile",
            "description": "1"
        }
    ],
    "pager": {
        "numberOfPages": 2,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "totalRecords": 6
    }
}
```

What I had try is:

```
items?:ItemsData[];
export interface ItemsData {
    id:number;
    itemNameER:string;
    itemNameEN:string;
    description:string;
}

retrieveAllItems(pageNumber: number = 0): void {
  this.erpservice.getAll(pageNumber)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      this.items=data.items;
        console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

How to extract `pager` data from JSON for the `numberOfPages`, `currentPage` and `totalRecords`?

**Updated post**

This is the information for the `getAll` return type.
So how to get pager data details?

```
export interface DataWrapper {
    items: ItemsData[];
}

getAll(pageNumber: number): Observable<DataWrapper> {
  let params = new HttpParams();

  if (pageNumber)
    params = params.append('pageNumber', pageNumber);

  let httpOptions = {
      params: params
  };
  return this.http.get<DataWrapper>(baseUrl,httpOptions);
}
```

What I had try is:

```
pager: any;
this.pager = data.pager;
```

But I get an error:

> Property 'pager' does not exist on type 'DataWrapper'.ts(2339)

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | paginate: { currentPage:pager.currentPage }; let i = index">
    {{ pager.numberOfPages * (pager.currentPage - 1) + i }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are asking. It looks like the first step would be to grab the pager data in your callback to `subscribe` via `data.pager` and assign that to something.

Comment: what type of variable will recieve data.pager

Comment: I think you need to update your definition of `DataWrapper` to include `pager: { numberOfPages: number; currentPage: number; totalRecords: number; };`

Comment: how to pass data please to pagination control as <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items | paginate: { currentPage:pager.currentPage }; let i = index">
    {{ pager.numberOfPages * (pager.currentPage - 1) + i }}
  </li>
</ul>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. The `DataWrapper` interface doesn't have a `pager` property.

You need to:

1. Add the `pager` property into `DataWrapper` interface.
2. Define the `IPager` interface.

```
export interface DataWrapper {
  items: ItemsData[];
  pager: IPager;
}

export interface IPager {
  numberOfPages: number;
  currentPage: number;
  totalRecords: number;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks done but small question if possible if i need to pass data to pagination control so how to do it

Comment: I think the requirement you mentioned in what I wrote in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75026936/8017690).